# WebStorm says argument types do not match parameters in the function bindActionCreaters

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, webstorm

I have a react component say *xyz*. I have an action-creator named say *abc* that gets called when a particular button is clicked in the component. Although the action-creator that I have imported from my actions folder works fine when I bind it to my component using *bindActionCreators*, WebStorm IDE highlights this *bindActionCreators* function in the file and a message saying "*argument types do not match function parameters*" is shown when I hover over the highlighted text.

I don't get why WebStorm is showing this. Please tell me a solution to fix this warning.

```js
   import { abc } from '../../actions/abc';
   import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

----------------------------------------------------------

   const mapActionToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return bindActionCreators({ abc }, dispatch);
   };
----------------------------------------------------------

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(xyz);

----------------------------------------------------------

export const UPDATE_BAR_STATE = 'UPDATE_BAR_STATE';

export const abc = (value) => {
    return({
        type: UPDATE_BAR_STATE,
        payload: value
    });
};
```

Reference Image:
[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Could you share your action creator `abc`?

Comment: Its showing this message in every component where i have used bindActionCreators!

Comment: I see. When your IDE reports an error that the code passes the wrong type of argument to a function, but you won't share what that argument (in this case, `{ abc }`) is, it's hard to assist you.

Comment: I added one of the many action creators which show this message.

Comment: FWIW, I have not seen this specific syntax before combined with `bindActionCreators`. Browsing the docs and Github, it's more common to see a single action creator passed to the function directly (not inside an object). Since we're talking about an IDE warning here, is `bindActionCreators(abc, dispatch);` perhaps worth trying?

Comment: This is a bug in WebStorm.